# Getting a weird error trying to set MultiLineString Coordinates

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to modify a multilinestring to add z coordinates to it but right now I am just trying to modify the line in anyway.

```
var line = event.features[4].getGeometry();
line.setLayout("XYZ");
line.setCoordinates([[-13550819.200333662,5691512.507689305,0],
    [-1350000.200333662,5200000.507689305,0],
    [-1300000.200333662,5000000.507689305,0]]);
```

is giving me the error:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: Failure: unsupported stride: undefined
```

I have inspected the object and the layout is indeed XYZ and the stride is 3. I presume stride is number of coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. MultilineStrings require more coordinates than what I was supplying.

```
line.setCoordinates([[[-13550819.200333662,5691512.507689305,0],
[-13550819.200333662,5691512.507689305,0]],[[-1350000.200333662,5200000.507689305,0],
[-13550819.200333662,5691512.507689305,0]],
    [[-1300000.200333662,5000000.507689305,0],
    [-13550819.200333662,5691512.507689305,0]]]);
```

Worked.